# Sending email to visual force page Email field on button click

Tags: email, button

I have a custom visual force page with several contact fields . User will enter data and hit save button. Once Save button is hit , it should send email to the emailid specified on emailid field on the page. I have written a controller to send email. As of now, I hard coded emailid for Toaddress field.This is working fine. How can I use !contact.email in controller so that the email will go to the !contact.email

Here is the part of the  controller

```
Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(2);
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

String[] toAddresses = new String[] {  'abcd@gmail.com' };

// Assign the addresses for the To and CC lists to the mail object.
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);  
mail.setReplyTo('xyz@yahoo.com');

mail.setSenderDisplayName('KFC');
mail.setSubject('Your upcoming shift with KFC');
mail.setBccSender(false);
mail.setPlainTextBody('Hi,I am sending a email');

// Send the email you have created.
```

Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

Here is the visual force page

```
  <apex:inputField value="{! contact.firstname}"/> 
  <apex:inputField value="{! contact.lastname}"/>    
  <apex:inputField value="{! contact.Title}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{! contact.email}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{! contact.phone}"/>     
  <apex:inputField value="{!contact.MailingStreet}"/>
  <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom" >  
  <apex:commandbutton value="Submit" action="{!save}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, since you're code is incomplete I'm going to make a quick assumption:

- You are using the standard controller with an extension

Your extension will NOT see the contact directly. You have to create a new variable in your extension  that holds the contact provided by the standard controller:

```
public Contact c {get; set;}
public classname (standardController con) {
    c = con.getRecord();
    //Note: the record will ONLY contain fields available on the page which should work
    //in your case. If you need to access more fields than what is on the page
    //you will need to query for the contact:
    // c = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Id = :con.getRecord().Id];
}
```

Once you do that, you should be able to fill your email address by referencing the new variable within your method:

```
Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(2);
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

**String[] toAddresses = new String[]();**
**toAddresses.add(c.Email);**

// Assign the addresses for the To and CC lists to the mail object.
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);  
mail.setReplyTo('xyz@yahoo.com');

mail.setSenderDisplayName('KFC');
mail.setSubject('Your upcoming shift with KFC');
mail.setBccSender(false);
mail.setPlainTextBody('Hi,I am sending a email');
```

If you are not using the standard set controller with an extension; rather, you are using a completely custom controller, that means you have something like this in your controller:

```
Contact contact = new Contact();
```

Shame on you...

Regardless, the answer is much easier:

```
Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(2);
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

**String[] toAddresses = new String[]();**
**toAddresses.add(contact.Email);**

// Assign the addresses for the To and CC lists to the mail object.
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);  
mail.setReplyTo('xyz@yahoo.com');

mail.setSenderDisplayName('KFC');
mail.setSubject('Your upcoming shift with KFC');
mail.setBccSender(false);
mail.setPlainTextBody('Hi,I am sending a email');
```

Comment: I did everything except    this line                            **toAddresses.add(c.Email);**                                                                                      After adding this line it worked..I was using c.Email for setToAddreses. Thank You.